# Scrape R For Loop - getting letter range A through Z for i

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the speakers for this year's SXSW: `https://schedule.sxsw.com/2019/speakers/alpha/A`

The end of the link has an `A`, but it goes through `Z` (like add a `B`, or a `C`, etc., to the end of the link.

Here's my attempt:

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

sxsw <- 'https://schedule.sxsw.com/2019/speakers/alpha/A'
page <- read_html(sxsw)

for (i in length(LETTERS)) {

    sxsw <- paste0('https://schedule.sxsw.com/2019/speakers/alpha/',  LETTERS[i])

    names <- page %>% 
     html_nodes(".px1 a") %>% 
     html_text()

}
```

I'm simply trying to append the entire range, so it returns all of the speaker names. If you take the `names` vector out of the loop, and run it, it pops up with all of the `A` names. I think this is a quick fix - think it has something to do with `LETTERS`. Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be updating `page` in your loop, after creating the `sxsw` url.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

tibble(
  url = paste0('https://schedule.sxsw.com/2019/speakers/alpha/',  LETTERS[1:26])
  )  %>% 
  mutate(
    names = map(url, read_html),
    names = map(names, html_nodes, ".px1 a"),
    names = map(names, html_text)
  ) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Code using lapply. I would recommend avoiding using loops in R

```
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
sxsw=list()
letters=toupper(letters)
sxsw <-lapply(letters,function(x){
read_html(paste0("https://schedule.sxsw.com/2019/speakers/alpha/",paste0(x)))%>% html_nodes(".px1 a") %>% 
  html_text()
}
)
```